# fopen not working in linux for a file with german characters in the name

Tags: c, linux, unicode, fopen

I have written a code in c, for file handling. The file name has some German characters in it. This code is working perfectly on Windows. But it is not working in Linux. fopen is giving 'Could not open file' error.
I have checked the file path, the file exists there. Also, I have read write permission for that folder.

The code is as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char *fileName = "/users/common/haëlMünchen.txt";

    FILE * pFile;
    char errorMessage[256];
    pFile = fopen (fileName,"r");
    if (pFile != NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stdout,"fopen example",errorMessage);
        fclose (pFile);
    }
    else
    {
    sprintf(errorMessage, "Could not open file %s", fileName);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", errorMessage);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Any inputs on this?

Comment: What's the encoding for your file and the file system paths?  Linux treats paths a just a bunch of bytes.  I suspect the encodings differ, and that's why you can't open it.  Since the bytes don't match exactly, it's not the same file.  You need to get the encoding right.

Comment: Likely Unicode (UTF-8) vs CP1252 (similar to ISO 8859-1 or 8859-15 for the characters shown).

Comment: BTW: does notepad preserve the appearance of the character ë ? I place my bets on character set encoding (some system presumes it's utf-8, because of the extended ascii characters...)

Comment: Use `ls h*chen.txt | od -t x1` to see the hex bytes for the file name on the file system.  Print out the bytes in `fileName` in your program in hex too.  Look for a difference.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux you could replace your `sprintf` call with

```
snprintf (errorMessage, sizeof(errorMessage), 
          "Could not open file %s - %m", fileName);
```

<sup>(A general hint is to avoid `sprintf` because of possible buffer overflows and only use `snprintf`)</sup>

If you want to avoid the GLibc specific `%m` format specifier, and use more standard functions, code

```
snprintf (errorMessage, sizeof(errorMessage), 
          "Could not open file %s - %s",
          fileName, strerror(errno));
```

and don't forget the `#include <errno.h>`, and read *carefully* the [errno(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html) man page.

BTW, you could avoid doing both `snprintf` and `printf` and simply code

```
fprintf (stderr, "Cannot open file %s - %s\n",
        fileName, strerror(errno));
```

<sup>(error reporting usually go to `stderr`, as Jonathan reminded)</sup>

Then run your program again. Perhaps you have an issue with character encoding (either in the source file, or in the filesystem).

You could also use `strace` (and perhaps `ltrace`) on your program to understand the actual syscalls it is doing.

Comment: The issue is not related to the sprintf. Issue is related to fopen with german characters. sprintf is used just for debugging purpose.

Comment: Indeed, but your usage of `sprintf` could be dangerous.

Comment: And you almost always want to tell the user what `errno` means when a function or syscall is failing...